# Does CSS Top and Left percentage values depend on screen resolution?

Tags: css

Im trying to align a jquery popup div to the center of my screen using top and left properties. I thought its better to give % values for these two properties so that the popup will be centered even if browser window is resized.

But when i actually resized the browser window its not resulting as expected.

So my doubt is, does the % value we specify for top, left properties depend upon the screen resolution? Or do they depend upon the parent container's size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They might. The percentage is relative to whatever element contains it. If that element happens to be the window itself, then yeah, it has to do with the resolution. In fact, it will always depend on the screen resolution as long as its parent does. And the same goes for the parent's parent, and so on. Kinda tough to grasp.

Basically, if any element "above" your element in the hierarchy of things *doesn't* depend on the resolution, neither does your element. But in order to see if it's parent depends on the resolution, you have to look at *that* element's parent. And the parent after that. And so on all the way to the top. Or you could test it out and look :)

It there's an absolute-positioned/sized element somewhere above it in the "hierarchy", then chances are it *doesn't* rely on screen resolution.

Comment: So, in order to correspond my popup size directly to the browser window, it should be put as a direct descendant of the body tag, right?

Comment: @Orbb eh..kinda. That'll work sometimes, but it won't work if the body is bigger than the window (i.e. scrollbars). Instead, I'd just get the window height and width using jQuery and use that to size it. You'll also probably want to add a resize event to the window and update the size of your element then.

Comment: Thanks for that jQuery tip Philip. Good thought. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The % depend on the next relative parent container's size.

Answer (score 0):

Percentages rely on their parents' size. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/tqWhL/4/ the red div is as wide as #a.

Since `body` is 100% of the *browser window* width, you could make your div a child of `body` and set it to 100% width.